# Symmetrize Armature does not Mirror bones correctly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

As stated in the heading, the armature symmetrize feature does not work properly. Although it does create missing bones, it does not position / mirror them correctly. (See Images)

-> Origin is set to Cursor, Cursor to World Center
-> Model is mirrored / built alongside the X-Axis

Thank you guys in advance for your help <3

[image: Before Clicking Symmetrize]
[image: After Clicking Symmetrize]

Comment: First thing, apply the rotation of your armature in Object mode

Comment: Already did that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetry operation will use the origin as the center, your origin is not correctly placed, move it (for example put the 3D cursor at the center of your mesh, then set the origin to 3D cursor):

[image]

Comment: Applying the armature's location in object mode will to the trick since the armature seem to have its base at the world center anyway.

Comment: it will move the right legs, so I'm not sure that it's what he wants, but yes you can apply the location, then move the legs back to their current position

Comment: Oh yeah it worked! Thanks a bunch mate!